# How log logcat in a bootloop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, boot-loop, logging

I have a Pipo X8 device, and I want to log logcat output because it gets stuck in a bootloop when I try to install Xposed framework.

The problem is that there is no USB, thus no USB-debugging, and Ethernet hasn't got time to start up before bootloop restarts. Hence, I can't trigger the logcat command. How can I log? Can I do a script that runs att startup and logs to file? How would i make such a script?

I believe making an app with BootBroadcastReceiver is far too late in the startup chain.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery installed? What do you mean there is no USB? Does the device not have a USB port?

Comment: I don't have any USB host ports no. No I don't have custom recovery. I have root however.  Can custom recovery like Clockworkmod log through a bootloop?